# How to find akka optimal configs in Play Framework 2.8

Tags: performance, playframework, akka

Here are my current configuration on our test ENV which is having 8 vCPU and 32 gigs ram

```
play.server.provider = "play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerProvider"

akka {
  loglevel = "INFO"
  log-config-on-start = on
  actor.default-dispatcher {
    executor = fork-join-executor
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 8
      parallelism-factor = 16.0
      parallelism-max = 64
      task-peeking-mode = "FIFO"
    }
  }
}
```

How can we calculate optimal values for Production servers ? (16 vCPU   and 64 gigs memory)

Comment: You need to read about akka actor dispatchers, and tune it accordingly:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.32/dispatchers.html

Comment: We are already following the doc. What we need is some help from experts to identify optimal values.

Comment: There are no general optimal values, because comparatively inconsequential differences in the code you're running (e.g. a stray `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`, though if you have that, it's likely that _no_ meaningful optimization is possible) can have a dramatic impact on how it should be configured.

Comment: The general advice is: look for cases where you're blocking, and move the blocking outside of `ExecutionContext`s/dispatchers which are designed for executing short tasks (these should never have more threads than host CPU threads...).  If you have tasks which use CPU for long work-units, then look for places you can yield in the middle of the work unit (e.g. insert a `flatMap` in a chain of `Future`s.